# Is there a throttle module or a way to do so in Play!Framework 2?

Tags: playframework-2.1, throttling

I'm building an API and I'd like to limit the requests made to it.

I'd like to limit it by the number of requests per user per time (hours, days), the whole number of requests (for all users) per time (hours, days), etc.

I searched around to find if there was a module for Play 2.1, but nothing came out. I tried here on SO to found if someone already had this problem, but only found it for Play 1.2.